# Environment: How to make apiBaseUrl dynamic?

Tags: angular

If my application is on production mode, I want the base URL of my API to be https://example.com/. If not, it should be http://localhost:8080/.

*environment.prod.ts*

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiBaseUrl: 'https://example.com/'
};
```

*environment.ts*

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'
};
```

Now if I use `environment` in my service, it asks me to import either `../environment/environment` or `../environments/environment.prod`.

How can I make it to import the one which is needed? If production mode, import `environment.prod`, if not, import `environment`.

Comment: You only import the `../environment/environment` when needed. The file will be replaced when you do a production build. Clearly outlined in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `angular.json` you have this section

```
    "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
```

this is doing the job for you

Answer (score 0):

If my application needs to be deploy on production server then we need to **environment.prod.ts** and if you need only for testing or work on local system then you need to **environment.ts**.

And both file should be keep under the **environment** folder and we can define **BaseUrl** for calling the api

For **Environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiBaseUrl: 'https://example.com/'
};
```

here you can see when you need for production server you need **production** key should be **true** otherwise you can keep with false

For **environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'
};
```

**environment.ts** is basically use for local environment so here you should put **production** key as false.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

in **angular.json** file you have to add below section.

```
"fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
```

Good Luck